# Sync WordPress users to Organizations instead of Individuals?

Tags: wordpress, contacts, contact-types, organization

We're using the WordPress integration of CiviCRM.

When we create a new WordPress user, civiCRM creates a new Contact - Good.

However, when it does this is creates an **Individual** type Contact. I want civiCRM to create **Organization** type Contact when I create a new WordPress user.

Is this possible? If not, am I able to convert **Individuals** into **Organizations**? I've seen an extension for it on the site but didn't know if it worked well or if there were alternatives.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: in general users are expected to be individuals as they have more fingers to type with than an organisation

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [Contact Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-editor) extension to change households to individuals.  It should change individuals to organizations but I have never tried this.

I can't speak towards changing CiviCRM contacts synced to WordPress users.  This could have an adverse effect so I would proceed cautiously.